# embed reportman to a delphi app

Tags: delphi, reportmanager

how can I embed reporman in a delphi app
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Reportman project on SourceForge](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/) includes [pretty clear documentation](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html) that includes instructions for [installing the components into Delphi 5 through Delph 2009](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/doc/delphicomp.html).  Are you having trouble with those components?

Answer (score 0):

The app was not working when deployed but it was a database dll problem, repman works fantastic.
Thanks for your answer
Regards